# How to set up a generic HOC connected to redux?

Tags: typescript

**TL;DR** as long as no generic used the TS says happy. And starts to complain with generics. Perhaps there is a need to put additional constraint on the generic typing. Please have a look at [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/embed/typescript-playground-export-bsy2x?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and may be you point on what I’m missing. For some reasons link shows a page with no diagnostics. Yet it marks error in edit mode as shown on the picture.

[image: the symbol specialized has somewhat conflicting typing]

The following piece is OK (definitions provided below).

```
  function specializeConnectPassThroughHOC(
    config: InnerConfProps & XFormConfig,
  ): (c: typeof Inner) => FC<OuterRtGivenProps & InnerDirectRtProps> {
    return (component) => {
      function xform(p: OuterRtProps): InnerXformRtProps {
        const c: XFormConfig = config;
        throw new Error(`using ${p} and ${c}`);
      };
      function mapStateToProps(
        rootState: any,
        ownProps: OuterRtGivenProps
      ): OuterRtReduxProps {
        throw new Error(`using ${rootState} and ${ownProps}`);
      }
      const specialized: FC<OuterRtProps & InnerDirectRtProps> = (p) => {
        const i = xform(p);
        return createElement(
          component,
          {
            ...config,
            ...p,
            ...i,    
          }
        );
      }
      return connect(mapStateToProps)(specialized);
    }
  }
```

and this one is not OK

```
function specializeConnectPassThroughHOC2<T>(
  config: InnerConfProps & XFormConfig,
): (c: FC<T & InnerConfProps>) => FC<OuterRtGivenProps & T> {
  return (component) => {
    function xform(p: OuterRtProps): InnerXformRtProps {
      const c: XFormConfig = config;
      throw new Error(`using ${p} and ${c}`);
    };
    function mapStateToProps(
      rootState: any,
      ownProps: OuterRtGivenProps
    ): OuterRtReduxProps {
      throw new Error(`using ${rootState} and ${ownProps}`);
    }
    const specialized: FC<OuterRtProps & T> = (p) => {
      const i = xform(p);
      return createElement(
        component,
        {
          ...config,
          ...p,
          ...i,
        }
      );
    }

    return connect(mapStateToProps)(/*some thing is missing and TS cries out*/specialized);
  }
}
```

There is a react component Inner. To work correctly it requires some properties of shape InnerProps to be passed to it. This InnerProps interface consists of two sub-sets InnerConfProps and InnerRtProps. Their values can be obtained at the design time and at runtime respectively. A function (specializeInner) creates a new component on the original Inner and helps with configuration part.

```
interface InnerConfProps { inncfg: string; }
interface InnerDirectRtProps { dirrt: string; }
interface InnerXformRtProps { xrt: string; }
type InnerRtProps = InnerDirectRtProps & InnerXformRtProps;
interface OuterRtGivenProps { givrt: string; }
interface OuterRtReduxProps { rxrt: string; }
type OuterRtProps = OuterRtGivenProps & OuterRtReduxProps;
interface XFormConfig { xfcfg: string; }
type InnerProps = InnerRtProps & InnerConfProps;
const Inner: FC<InnerProps> = () => {
  return null;
}
function specializeInner(
  component: typeof Inner,
  config: InnerConfProps,
): FC<InnerRtProps> {
  return (p) => createElement(
    component,
    {
      ...config,
      ...p
    },
  );
}
```

Now we are going a step further. The specializeFromOuter function should produce a component that receives properties of OuterRtProps and transforms them into InnterRtProps using the xform inner function.

```
function specializeFromOuter(
  component: typeof Inner,
  config: InnerConfProps,
): FC<OuterRtProps> {
  const xform: (
    p: OuterRtProps,
  ) => InnerRtProps = () => { throw new Error(); }
  return (p) => {
    const i = xform(p);
    return createElement(
      component,
      {
        ...config,
        ...i
      }
    )
  }
}
```

The next step is to realize that xform function also needs some configuration to do its work. Let’s say the shape of xform configuration is XFormConfig. This way we are getting specializeFromOuterWithConfig function.

```
function specializeFromOuterWithConfig(
  component: typeof Inner,
  config: InnerConfProps & XFormConfig,
): FC<OuterRtProps> {
  const xformcfg: (p: OuterRtProps) => InnerRtProps = (p) => {
    const xc: XFormConfig = config;
    throw new Error(`using ${p} and ${xc}`);
  }

  return (p) => {
    const i = xformcfg(p);
    return createElement(
      component,
      {
        ...config,
        ...i
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Next step comes when we find that OuterRtProps properties are also split into two parts. One section comes directly from upper parent and has shape OuterRtGivenProps. The other OuterRtReduxProps section should be extracted from redux store. And now we want to connect the created outer component to redux store.  The specializeWithConnect does this.

```
function specializeWithConnect(
  component: typeof Inner,
  config: InnerConfProps & XFormConfig
): FC<OuterRtGivenProps> {
  const xform: (
    p: OuterRtProps,
  ) => InnerRtProps = () => {
    throw new Error();
  };
  function mapStateToProps(
    rootState: any,
    ownProps: OuterRtGivenProps,
  ): OuterRtReduxProps {
    throw new Error(`using ${rootState} and ${ownProps}`);
  }
  const specialized: FC<OuterRtProps> = (p) => {
    const i = xform(p);
    return createElement(
      component,
      {
        ...config,
        ...i,
      }
    );
  }
  return connect(mapStateToProps)(specialized);
}
```

One more step further. Suppose that InnerRtProps shape also consists of two section one that need to be transformed and the other that do not. The specializeConnectPassThrough function does this.

```
function specializeConnectPassThrough(
  component: typeof Inner,
  config: InnerConfProps & XFormConfig,
): FC<OuterRtGivenProps & InnerDirectRtProps> {
  function xform(p: OuterRtProps): InnerXformRtProps {
    const c: XFormConfig = config;
    throw new Error(`using ${p} and ${c}`);
  };
  function mapStateToProps(
    rootState: any,
    ownProps: OuterRtGivenProps
  ): OuterRtReduxProps {
    throw new Error(`using ${rootState} and ${ownProps}`);
  }
  const specialized: FC<OuterRtProps & InnerDirectRtProps> = (p) => {
    const i = xform(p);
    return createElement(
      component,
      {
        ...config,
        ...p,
        ...i,

      }
    );
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(specialized);
}
```

All the above constructs use the throw to stay short and syntactically correct.

We can convert the construct to HOC specializeConnectPassThroughHOC.

The final step is to make the specializeXxx function generic. It is easy to realize that the construct does not depend on the shape of InnerDirectRtProps and we can replace with a generic. BUT TS has its own opinion.

Comment: I suggest setup a TS playground.

Comment: It seams the issue related to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/31363, or is it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the construct above rooted deep inside the `connect`'s definitely typed typing. The better way is to use the hooks mechanics. It seams the following answers the question

```
type P3<T extends {}> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, keyof InnerConfProps & keyof OuterRtGivenProps>>;

export function specializeConnectPassThroughHOC3<T extends {}>(
  config: InnerConfProps & XFormConfig,
): (c: FC<P3<T> & InnerConfProps>) => FC<P3<T> & OuterRtGivenProps> {
  function xform(p: OuterRtProps): InnerXformRtProps {
    const c: XFormConfig = config;
    throw new Error(`using ${p} and ${c}`);
  };

  function mapStateToProps(
    rootState: any,
    ownProps: OuterRtGivenProps
  ): OuterRtReduxProps {
    throw new Error(`using ${rootState} and ${ownProps}`);
  }

  const makePreSelector: () =>
    (rootState: any, p: OuterRtGivenProps) =>
      InnerXformRtProps = () => 
        createSelector(
          state => state,
          p => p,
          (state, p) => {
            const outerReduxProps = mapStateToProps(state, p);
            return xform({ ...p, ...outerReduxProps });
          },
        )

  return (component) => {
    return (p) => {
      const selector = useMemo(makePreSelector,[]);
      const i = useSelector((state) => selector(state, p));
      return createElement(
        component,
        {
          ...config,
          ...p,
          ...i,
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

For demo purposes I used the same xform and mapStateToProps functions.In production these should be optimized.